# getting zip code plus four digits using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = '92675-2042 BL-17-1111, 18S-8 01345-1345 L1-12 23345-0921 45312-8733 21-year old, 40-year-old, 67-years, BL-14-111, 91-years, AL-1-2, 01-13-2019, 1-22-2001'
reg = r'\\b\\d{5}(?:[ -]\\d{4})?\\b'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
```

I have the following `reg` taken from [Extract 5 digit zip code from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162104/extract-5-digit-zip-code-from-string) that returns an empty list `[]`. I want `reg` to get all the zip codes in `s` plus four digits attached to them e.g `'92675-2042'`. I would like my output to be

```
 ['92675-2042', '01345-1345', '23345-0921', '45312-8733']
```

How do I tweak `reg = r'\\b\\d{5}(?:[ -]\\d{4})?\\b'` to get my desired output?

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your third line with

```
reg = r'\b\d{5}(?:[ -]\d{4})?\b'
```

Then you will get what you want:

```
>>> import re                                                                                                                
>>> s = '92675-2042 BL-17-1111, 18S-8 01345-1345 L1-12 23345-0921 45312-8733 21-year old, 40-year-old, 67-years, BL-14-111, 91-years, AL-1-2, 01-13-2019, 1-22-2001'
>>> reg = r'\b\d{5}(?:[ -]\d{4})?\b'
>>> r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
>>> r1
['92675-2042', '01345-1345', '23345-0921', '45312-8733']
```

When you use `r''` you do not need to double up on the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the pattern:

```
\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?!\S)
```

This says to match either 5 digits, or 5 digits plus a dash and a 4 digit PO box code.

```
s = '92675-2042 BL-17-1111, 18S-8 01345-1345 L1-12 23345-0921 45312-8733 21-year old, 40-year-old, 67-years, BL-14-111, 91-years, AL-1-2, 01-13-2019, 1-22-2001'
matches = re.findall(r'\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?!\S)', s)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['92675-2042', '01345-1345', '23345-0921', '45312-8733']
```